# how could you rewrite this query doesn't use a sub query?

Tags: sql

Since a sub query returns rows and columns, you can join against a sub query just like you can join against a normal table.

```
SELECT 
    P.ProductCode, I.QuantityInStock as Qty, P.Title, P.Price 
FROM 
    Products as P 
JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM Inventory) as I on (P.ProductCode = I.ProductCode);
```

How could you rewrite this query so it doesn't use a sub query?

am trying to rewrite but am not sure is correct

```
SELECT P.ProductCode, I.QuantityInStock as Qty, P.Title, P.Price
FROM Products as P
WHERE Inventory as I on (P.ProductCode = I.ProductCode);
```

Is this correct?

Comment: what database are you using??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.ProductCode, I.QuantityInStock as Qty, P.Title, P.Price 
FROM   Products as P 
JOIN   Inventory as I on P.ProductCode = I.ProductCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're selecting ALL columns from Inventory you can just do

```
SELECT 
    P.ProductCode, I.QuantityInStock as Qty, P.Title, P.Price 
FROM 
    Products as P 
JOIN 
    Inventory I on P.ProductCode = I.ProductCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.ProductCode, I.QuantityInStock as Qty, P.Title, P.Price
FROM Products as P, Inventory as I
WHERE P.ProductCode = I.ProductCode
```